# jQuery ajax cross domain post to WCF rest service

Tags: wcf, rest, jquery

I'm trying to make a cross domain POST to a WCF rest service. Following is my service code that gets the request

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public SampleItem Create(SampleItem instance)
    {

        instance.StringValue += " -success";
        return instance;
    }
```

And on the client side I have the following jquery ajax call

```
 var input = { "Id": 10, "StringValue": "Test Value" };

                $("#post").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:50577/Service1/",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: JSON.stringify(input),
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(item) {
                            $("#itemId").val(item.Id);
                            $("#name").val(item.StringValue);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            alert("error " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

When I debug the code on server side the request is coming to the method but the instance argument is null. In the same project I have a cross domain get which is working without any problems. 
If i change the client to be in the same domain and change datatype to json it works fine.

So is cross domain post just not possible? Or is there something else I need to do to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your first question, since you are able to debug the service!

The JSON input to the AJAX call isn't in the correct format. Try this:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({instance : input}),
...
```